# Gitlab - AutoSync / Replicate Local Server from/to Cloud Server

Tags: git, automation, gitlab, devops

I have 2 Gitlab servers:

Server **A** that runs on the cloud and accessible from https://git.example.com

and

Server **B** that runs on the local network and accessible only through local computers by an IP address or a fake domain that redirects locally http://local.git (DNS spoof)

How can I make both git servers **A** & **B** mirrored/synced/replicated where:

> - Server **B** would automatically push any local work/changes to server **A**
>
> After that (or before)
>
> - Server **B** will check server **A** for any differences in any repo and make sure both are 100% synced - in another meaning, server **B** would pull the changes from server **A** because some people might push changes directly to server **A** from outside this local network.

I don't think the priority matters because both servers will be 100% the same at the end - sorry I'm not a developer (or use git a lot) but more of an IT guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most stable solution would be to mirror your servers at the repository level.

GitLab has an internal mechanism for doing this for you (see: https://gitlab.com/help/workflow/repository_mirroring).

The alternative (since you won't have access to the file system on your hosted GitLab instance) would be to create a script to iteratively "mirror" your repositories using `git push --mirror ..`.